# Embedding navigation controllers in a tabbarcontroller that is not the root view

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I’m having some trouble with a integrating a navigation controller inside a tabbarcontroller that is not in the root view. My issue is that the root view, which leads to the tabbarcontroller is embedded in a navigation controller. Naturally, since the root view leads to the tabbarcontroller then each tab uses that root view’s navigation controller. Ideally I’d like to wrap each tab in its own navigation controller so that I could adjust them accordingly. I’ve tried using a modal segue and it allows me to put each tab in its own navigation controller, but this implementation does not work due to a sliding side menu plugin I am using. Embedding a navigationcontroller in each tab causes my autosizing to think there are two navbbars (because there are.) Any ideas? Is there a way I can maybe remove the navigationcontroller from  latter views and keep it on the root?

Answer (score 0):

TabBarControllers are meant to be root controllers, so your best course of action is likely going to be restructuring the navigation of your app to fit this paradigm. If you don't want the TabBarController to be the first view that the user sees (for instance, if your app has a login screen) then you can just modally present the login view controller over the top of the TabBarController when the app starts up (if needed).

Barring that, if you're just looking for a quick fix for your double navigation bar issue, you just want to get around your double navigation bar issue, you could just set the Top Bar property for your NavigationController to "none", as shown below.

[image]

Comment: My root view is a table that loads specific information into the tabbarcontroller depending on which cell was chosen. I'm not sure how to tailor that to fit this paradigm. Is there really no other way?

Can I set the top bar property conditionally? I want it to still show on my root view, but not my tab view.

Comment: I mean, you're likely to be able to get it to work, but there be dragons that way, you know? If you'd like to programmatically hide/show your NavigationController's nav bar, you can use the setNavigationBarHidden:animated: method when loading view controllers.